# Slow MySql query with order by limit with index

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a query generated by Entity Framework, that looks like this:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`ExpireAfterUTC`, 
`Extent1`.`FileId`, 
`Extent1`.`FileHash`, 
`Extent1`.`PasswordHash`, 
`Extent1`.`Size`, 
`Extent1`.`TimeStamp`, 
`Extent1`.`TimeStampOffset`
FROM `files` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `containers` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`ContainerId` = `Extent2`.`Id`
 ORDER BY 
`Extent1`.`Id` ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

It runs painfully slow.
I have indexes on files.Id (PK), files.ContainerId(FK), containers.Id(PK) and I don't understand why mysql seems to be doing a full sort before returning the required records, even though there already is an index on the Id column.

Further more, this data is displayed in a grid which supports filters, sorts and pagination and a good use of the indexes is highly required.

Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FileId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ContainerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ContainerGuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `Guid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `ExpireAfterUTC` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` binary(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FileHash` tinyblob NOT NULL,
  `Size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TimeStamp` double NOT NULL,
  `TimeStampOffset` double NOT NULL,
  `FilePostId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FilePostGuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `AttributeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FileId_UNIQUE` (`FileId`),
  KEY `Files_ContainerId_FK` (`ContainerId`),
  KEY `Files_AttributeId_FK` (`AttributeId`),
  KEY `Files_FileId_index` (`FileId`),
  KEY `Files_FilePostId_index` (`FilePostId`),
  KEY `Files_Guid_index` (`Guid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Files_AttributeId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`AttributeId`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Files_ContainerId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`ContainerId`) REFERENCES `containers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Files_FilePostsId_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`FilePostId`) REFERENCES `fileposts` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=977942 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `containers` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Guid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `AesKey` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  `FileCount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `Containers_Guid_index` (`Guid`),
  KEY `Containers_Name_index` (`Name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You will notice there are some other relationships in the files table, which I have left out just to simplify the query without affecting the observed behavior.

Here is also an output from EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |  table  | type  |    possible_keys     |          key          | key_len |               ref                | rows  | filtered |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Extent2 | index | PRIMARY              | Containers_Guid_index |      16 | NULL                             |     9 | 100.00   | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Extent1 | ref   | Files_ContainerId_FK | Files_ContainerId_FK  |       4 | netachmentgeneraltest.Extent2.Id | 73850 | 100.00   |                                              |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Files table has ~900000 records (and counting) and containers has 9.
This issue only occurs when ORDER BY is present.
Also, I can't do much in terms of modifying the query because it is generated by Entity Framework. I did as much as I could with the LINQ query in order to simplify it (at first it had some horrible sub queries which executed even slower).

Query hints (as in force index) are not a solution here either, because EF does not support such features.

I am mostly hoping to find some database level optimizations to do.

For those who didn't spot the tags, the database in question is MySql.

Comment: Can you try a STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the order it joins the table. Hopefully allowing it to use the index on files.id for the sort.

Comment: @Kickstart Indeed, straight_join works! The result is instant. But how about using this withing Entity Framework? Any clues?

Comment: Afraid no experience of it. However it might be worth running ANALYZE TABLE .... on each of the tables. Might be the details are out of date hence choosing an inefficient join order

Comment: @Kickstart I ran ANALYZE TABLE on both tables, but still no joy.

Comment: If container has only 9 rows, can you remove the KEY `Files_ContainerId_FK` (`ContainerId`)?

Comment: @NevilleK MySQL Workbench tells me I have to delete the foreign key to containers, also. Which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only uses one index per table. Right now, it's preferring to use the foreign key index so the join is efficient, but that means that the sort is not using an index.

Try creating a compound index on `ContainerId, filedID`

Comment: I have already tried a compound index on id, containerid, but mysql only uses it if I force it to. The results are as expected, but I cannot use query hints from entity framework. Are you sure you got the column order right? By using that index, even if I force it to, there's no impact.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially your query:

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM `files` e1 INNER JOIN
     `containers` e2
     ON e1.`ContainerId` = e2.`Id`
ORDER BY e1.`Id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

You can *try* an index on `files(id, ContainerId)`.  This might inspire MySQL to use the composite index, focused on the `order by`.

It would probably be more likely if the query were phrased as:

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM `files` e1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM containers e2 WHERE e1.`ContainerId` = e2.`Id`)
ORDER BY e1.`Id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

There is one way that does work to use the indexes.  However, it depends on something in MySQL that is not documented to work (although it does in practice).  The following will read the data in order, but it incurs the overhead of materializing the subquery -- but not for a sort:

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM (SELECT e1.*
      FROM files e1
      ORDER BY e1.id ASC
     ) e1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM containers e2 WHERE e1.`ContainerId` = e2.`Id`)
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: I have already tried a compound index on id, containerid, but mysql only uses it if I force it to. The results are as expected, but I cannot use query hints from entity framework.